# Sports series? I’m confused how to calculate using an inequality

Tags: probability, statistics, distribution-theory

Ok so the inequality on this problem is throwing me off

Suppose that two teams (team A and team B) play a series of games to determine a winner. In a best-of-three series, the games end as soon as one team has won two games. In a best-of-five series, the games end as soon as one team has won three games, and so on. Assume that team A’s probability of winning any one game is p, where .5 < p < 1. Also assume that the outcomes are independent from game to game.

What is the exact probability team A will win a three game series, as a function of p? I know this should be straightforward, I just can’t seem to grasp it

Comment: You can break this down with a tree diagram.  The possible outcomes that result in $A$ winning the series would be from $A$'s perspective: Win - Win,  Win - Loss - Win, or Loss - Win - Win.  Use the multiplication rule of probability and that the outcomes of each game are independent of one another and then the summation rule of probability to finish the calculations.

Comment: For longer series, it often helps calculations to pretend that they continue to play exhibition match games even after a winner is determined for the series.  This allows you to use tools like the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to simplify calculations.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok so that makes sense when using the tree diagram, but what probabilities would I use for team A winning if it isn’t an exact probability? If I were to use binomial distribution, what would I plug in for the probability parameter, since it’s multiple values?

Comment: "*what probabilities would I use for team $A$ winning if it isn't an exact probability*"  You seem to be misunderstanding the question.  It *is* an exact probability and it goes by the name $p$ and label $p$.  Rather than asking the infinitely many questions "What is the probability that $A$ wins the series if each game $A$ wins with probability $0.5$? if each game $A$ wins with probability $0.51$? if each game $A$ wins with probability $0.52,\dots$? if each game $A$ wins with probability $0.999\dots$?" they chose to instead ask you the single question where $p$ is unspecified but still exact.

Comment: Just because *we* don't know the value of $p$ does not stop us from being able to use it in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

P(A win series) = P(WW)+P(LWW)+P(WLW)
$$P(A)=p^2+p^2(q)+p^2(q)=p^2+2p^2q$$
P(B win series) = P(LL)+P(LWL)+P(WLL)
$$P(B)= q^2+2q^2p$$

$$P(A)+P(B)=p^2+q^2+2p^2q+2q^2p=1$$

In a best of $2n+1$ case 
$$P_{2n+1}(A)=p^{n+1}+\binom{n+1}{1}p^{n+1}q+\binom{n+2}{2}p^{n+1}q^2....+\binom{2n}{n}p^{n+1}q^n \\ =p^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}q^k$$